# Error "Valid intents must be provided for the Client"

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I get the error "Valid intents must be provided for the Client" whenever I run my discord bot.
Anyone no how to fix the error?

my code is

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const client = new Discord.Client()
const TOKEN = ("TOKEN")
client.on("ready", () => {

  console.log('Logged in as $  {client.user.tag}!')
})

client.on("message", msg => {

  if (msg.content === "Facts about disneyland") {
    msg.reply("Before Disney chose Anaheim, he almost built his park on a seven-acre studio lot in Burbank. The meager playground would be called “Walt Disney’s America.” Fortunately for us all, his dreams grew quickly.")
  }
})
client.login(TOKEN)
```

Everything I have tried has not worked

Answer (score -1):

It appears that when initializing your bot you didn't add any intents. In order to fix this you have to add `{ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] }` to `const client = new Discord.Client()`

This would make your code look like this:

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });
```

You will also have to import the GatewayIntentBits from discord.js, so in order to do this you have to add `const { GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js")`

I also noticed that in your client on ready handler you used a `'` instead of `` ` `` and tried using `$  {client.user.tag}` This will not work correctly as `'` will enter `$  {client.user.tag}`, literally, instead of the bot's tag. To fix this you will have to replace `'` with `` ` ``. You will also have to remove the spaces, and put the `$` and `{` together.

In the end, this will make your code look like this:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const { GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js")
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });
const TOKEN = ("TOKEN")
client.on("ready", () => {

  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})

client.on("message", msg => {

  if (msg.content === "Facts about disneyland") {
    msg.reply("Before Disney chose Anaheim, he almost built his park on a seven-acre studio lot in Burbank. The meager playground would be called “Walt Disney’s America.” Fortunately for us all, his dreams grew quickly.")
  }
})
client.login(TOKEN)
```

Comment: It went online but when I did the message to trigger it it did nothing I even tried to add a prefix any ideas

Comment: @vtf6259 just send `Facts about disneyland` and it should work

Comment: I moved on to java.